# Access: Allow value list edits

Tags: ms-access

In an Access table, I have 2 columns that take the value from a list.

In one case (**case A**), the `Row Source` is a simple list of values entered manually.

In the other case (**case B**), the `Row Source` is a list taken from another table (`[Lawfulness of Processing].[Lawfulness of Processing]`).

More than one item of the list can be selected for each field. For this reason, I have set `Allow Multiple Values` as `Yes`.

During the selection, I would like to edit the list. For this reason, I have set `Allow Value List Edits` as `Yes`.

The problem is that the button to edit the list (third image) is visible only in the case A and not in the case B.

Is there some issue related to the use of a table as `Row Source`?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is confusing. The question description above says that table A comes from another table yet the image of A shows it being a static list. Please edit the question so that the description matches the images.

Comment: @SamM ahahahah sorry you have right!! I inverted them. Now they are correct.

Comment: "Edit List Items" is only for Value Lists. You will have to implement your own editing strategy for other Row Source Types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to edit list items with a list bound to a table, you need to specify the *list edit form* property, and set it to a form that edits the table your combo box rowset is bound to.

After specifying the list edit form, you can click the *edit list* button, and the specified form will open.

If you instead want to open the table, you can create a form, and add VBA to open the table and close the form as soon as it's opened.

Comment: ok thanks. I have set the `List Items Edit Form` and know the `Edit List Items` button appears when I am selecting the items in the **table** environment. But when I am in the **form** environment, the `Edit List Items` button is not visible. Do you know why?

Comment: Are you sure you've set the property on both the form and the table?